# How to display associated json data in grid in extjs4?

Tags: json, extjs, extjs4.1, extjs-mvc

I am working in extjs4 mvc where I am getting stuck at a point. Actually I want to display associated json data in grid in extjs4. I tried and searched a lot but not yet get problem solved.

Here is my some code

1. my view file:

   ```
   Ext.define('AM.view.user.List' ,{
       extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',
       alias : 'widget.userlist',
       title : 'All Users',
       store: 'Users',
       columns: [
           {header: 'Name',  dataIndex: 'name',  flex: 1},
           {header: 'Email', dataIndex: 'email', flex: 1},
           {header:'title',dataIndex:'title',flex:1}       //I tried 
       ]
    });
   ```
2. Controller file:

   ```
   Ext.define('AM.controller.Users', {
       extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
       stores: ['Users'],
       models: ['User','Book'],
       views: ['user.Edit', 'user.List'],
       refs: [{
           ref: 'usersPanel',
           selector: 'panel'
       }],
       init: function() {

        this.control({
                'viewport > userlist dataview': {
                    itemdblclick: this.editUser
                },
                'useredit button[action=save]': {
                    click: this.updateUser
                }
            });

       }
   });
   ```
3. User model file:

   ```
    Ext.define('AM.model.User', {
       extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
   fields: ['id', 'name', 'email'],
   hasMany: {
       model: 'AM.model.Book',
       //model: 'Book', 
       foreignKey: 'userId', 
       name: 'books'
   },
   proxy: {
       type: 'ajax',
       api: {
           read: 'data/users.json',
           update: 'data/updateUsers.json'
       },
       reader: {
           type: 'json',
           root: 'users',
           successProperty: 'success'
       }
   }
   });
   ```
4. User store file :--

   ```
   Ext.define('AM.store.Users', {
      extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
      model: 'AM.model.User',
      autoLoad: true
   });
   ```
5. Book model file:

   ```
   Ext.define('AM.model.Book',{
       extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
       fields: [
           {name: 'id', type: 'int'},
           {name: 'title', type: 'string'}, //,mapping:'record[0].title'    not working
           {name: 'userId', type: 'int'}
       ]     
   });
   ```
6. json file:

   ```
   {
   "success": "true",
   "users": [
       {
           "id": "1",
           "name": "shilpa",
           "email": "shilpa@sencha.com",
           "books": [
               {
                   "id": "10",
                   "title": "c++",
                   "userId": "1"
               }
           ]
       }
   ]
   }
   ```
7. here is the screenshot:

[image]

please give me some suggestion to display associated data in grid.

Comment: You want to display the title of just the first book?. Would you prefer to display the title of all the related books separeted by commas or using two diferent grids that when you select a user in the first grid, it shows all the related books in the second grid.

Comment: I just i want to display the title of all the related books seperated by commas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access all the books in the column renderer and construct the string you need. It would be something like this:

```
{
    text: 'Books',
    renderer: function (val, meta, record) {
        var books = '';
        record.books().each(function(bookRecord, index, count) {
            books = books + bookRecord.get('title') + ',';
        });
        return books;
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/alexrom7/YQXC8/1/